# Bot Composer - Create and get dynamic named variable value

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have a loop that iterates over an array and must generate a variable by concatenating a text with the index of the loop.
I am doing the assignment with the following code (I think this part is correct):

```
dialog.answer_${dialog.foreach.index} //result expected: dialog.answer_0, dialog.answer_1, ...
```

The question is how to access this variable. I tried to view the content by displaying a message with "Send a response", but it shows me empty.

```
- Answer: ${dialog.answer_dialog.foreach.index}
or
- Answer: ${dialog.answer_${dialog.foreach.index}} //this causes syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how to access this variable. I tried to view the content by displaying a message with "Send a response", but it shows me empty.

I'm not sure I'm following the question/situation, so apologies if I am misunderstanding.

Typically you use the index property (default of `dialog.foreach.index`) and value property (default of `dialog.foreach.value`).

> I am doing the assignment with the following code (I think this part is correct)

I 'm following on this, and yeah; that looks correct.

> The question is how to access this variable. I tried to view the content by displaying a message with "Send a response", but it shows me empty.

So, `dialog.answer_${dialog.foreach.index}`, will just be a string. As you mentioned as an example; this would be something like `dialog.answer_0` or `dialog.answer_1`.

For this example; let's assume we're on the first loop and this sting is `dialog.answer_0`. Are you wanting the actual text to be `Answer: dialog.answer_0`? If so, your response would just be `- Answer: dialog.answer_${dialog.foreach.index}` as the index `0` would replace `${dialog.foreach.index}` and you would get a response of `- Answer: dialog.answer_0`.

The memory scope of `dialog.answer_dialog` doesn't exist (as far as you've shared) and you won't be able to get anything out of that unless you've specifically stored something there.

Again; I may be misunderstanding, so please clarify if needed.